# Linq order by not ordering

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the query:

```
var q = 
    (
        from c in db.tblArcadeGamePlays 
        join a in db.tblProfiles on c.UserID equals a.UserID
        where c.UserID != 0
        orderby c.Date descending
        select new { c.UserID, c.tblForumAuthor.Username, a.EmailAddress }
    )
    .Distinct()
    .Take(12);
```

This takes the correct records, but isn't ordering them.  If I switch the orderby to asc/desc it has no affect!  Can anyone point out what I can do to return the records newest first?

**Edit**

It's returning the correct ordering of results if the `Distinct()` is removed, but it's now returning the same user record over and over again (I only want each user to appear once)

Comment: @Haris The orderby after the select wont compile as it's invalid linq

Comment: What type is c.Date? Do you mean that Asc and Desc return the same results?

Comment: @Strillo `c.Date` is `datetime` and yes Asc and Desc return same results even though both returned records have different date values

Comment: It returns the correct record ordering if I remove the Distinct() clause but it returns the same user over and over (I only want distinct users).  The Distinct() seems to just ruin the ordering

Comment: Sounds like you have several c records belonging to the same user. The distinct just returns one user object per each combination of Id, Name and Address. Isn't this the result you are looking for? Your selected object does not contain a date field, so where is the wrong ordering?

Comment: Oh I see. You want to return the list of users ordered by their respective most recent date, is this correct?

Comment: What happens if you exclude tblForumAuthor and include c.Date in the select new ?

Comment: @Strillo I'm trying to get those records yes but ordered by the date they last appear.  I just added the *first* date for the user in the select and ordered after the distinct now and it works!  Thanks!

Comment: @BalamBalam that would cause the same user to be returned multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `distinct` list to be ordered by the newest item in each set, right?

To do this, you should use a `group by`.  You'll have to `order` twice, once within each set, and once again for the entire list:

```
var q = 
    from s in 
    (
        from c in db.tblArcadeGamePlays 
        join a in db.tblProfiles on c.UserID equals a.UserID
        where c.UserID != 0
        select new { c.UserId, c.TblForumAuthor.Username, a.EmailAddress, c.Date }
    )
    group s by new { g.UserId, g.Username, g.EmailAddress } into g
    orderby g.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).First().Date descending
    select g.Key
    )
    .Take(12);
```

The `orderby` part might look confusing, but it's simply: **order the groups by the first date within each group**

Comment: It actually might be more efficient to do `orderby g.Select(s => s.Date).Min() descending`

Answer (score 2):

Distinct is undoing your OrderBy. Do your sorting after the distinct and you'll be fine.

Comment: How can I `Distinct()` the records if the select contains `c.Date`?  This would mean that every record would count as distinct.  There are multiple `c` records for each user.

Comment: Try selecting the last tblArcadeGamePlays per user, and order by that date.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, this is the working query:

```
var q = (from c in db.tblArcadeGamePlays
            join a in db.tblProfiles on c.UserID equals a.UserID
            where c.UserID != 0
            select new {
                c.UserID,
                c.tblForumAuthor.Username,
                a.EmailAddress,
                Date = (from d in db.tblArcadeGamePlays where d.UserID == c.UserID orderby d.Date descending select new { d.Date}).Take(1).Single().Date
            })
.Distinct()
.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Date)
.Take(12);
```

You need to specify a date in the select so I took the last date for that particular user, and ordered by after `Distinct()`.  Hard to explain but makes more sense if you read through it.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
var q = (from c in db.tblArcadeGamePlays  
join a in db.tblProfiles on c.UserID equals a.UserID 
where c.UserID != 0 
select new { c.UserID, c.tblForumAuthor.Username, a.EmailAddress })
.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date) 
.Distinct() 
.Take(12);
```

Comment: Invalid syntax sorry, c.Date is not defined (it's trying to look for it in the select)